# local files Showing 404 error in angularjs 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am new to angular 4; I have installed using `npm install -g @angular/cli`. Then created a new project using `ng new my-app`.

```
|-src
|  -app
|    app.component.css
|    app.component.html
|    app.component.spec.ts
|    app.component.ts
|    app.module.ts
```

`src` folder contains app folder which contains corresponding above css, ts, html files. Now I have added an image in the app folder

```
|-src
|  -app
|    app.component.css
|    app.component.html
|    app.component.spec.ts
|    app.component.ts
|    app.module.ts
|    image.jpg
```

The problem is, when I add a `<img src="image.jpg">` tag in app.component.html, it is showing a `404` error in the console. But if I add a style like `background: url('image.jpg');` in app.component.css, it's working.

Any suggestions please? Thank you.

Comment: give image path location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put all of your public assets (e.g. images) in the `src/assets` folder

Then you can access them through your `html/css` like this `/assets/image.jpg`

The file structure should be as follows:

```
- src
  - app
  - assets
      image.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks thats working, first why do we need to do that? any thing that added to assets can be accessible like .json files like that?

Comment: The point is to separate your app code files (ts, html and css) from the public assets files, that way the images are accessible to the browser. so yes, everything in you assets folder is accessible publicly, through `my-domain.com/assets/some_file`

Answer (score 0):

You need to give image path location. You can do this as:

```
<img src="./image.jpg">
```

This way you can give reference of your image.jpg file.